# Linking video to an HTML anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-video, anchor

I am trying to make a website that has an anchor link to "watch the video", what I want to do is to link a video to the anchor tag and when someone clicks on the link, the video appears on the same webpage but upon webpage and behind the video, page should be lightened. Help me to figure this out.

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-one">Watch Video</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-two">Explore More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What type of videos do you want to show? YouTube? Vimeo?

Comment: @djuarez I want the YouTube video.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $iframe = $('iframe'),
    $videoLink = $('.video-link'),
    playerTemplate = '<div class="player"><div class="player__video"><div class="video-filler"></div><button class="video-close">&times;</button><iframe class="video-iframe" src="{{iframevideo}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div/>';


$videoLink.on('click', function(e) {
    var localTemplate = '',
        videoWidth = parseInt($(this).data('width')),
        videoHeight = parseInt($(this).data('height')),
        videoAspect = ( videoHeight / videoWidth ) * 100,
        // elements
        $player = null,
        $video = null,
        $close = null,
        $iframe = null;

    e.preventDefault();

    localTemplate = playerTemplate.replace('{{iframevideo}}', $(this).prop('href'));

    $player = $(localTemplate);

    $player
        .find('.video-filler')
        .css('padding-top', videoAspect + '%');

    $close = $player
        .find('.video-close')
        .on('click', function() {
            $(this).off().closest('.player').hide().remove();
        });

    $player.appendTo('body').addClass('js--show-video');
});
```

```css
.video-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #f03;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

/* --- */
.player {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.player__video {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%; 
    width: auto;
    max-width: 75%;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,.95);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.js--show-video { opacity: 1; }

.video-filler {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.video-close {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -30px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}

.video-iframe {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<a class="video-link" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ONaPq2L-MRg?html5=1" data-width="1920" data-height="1080">Open video</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need a video tag and also use some JavaScript.

Not sure if that what you meant, but here is a simple implemnation of what I think you meant. 
`<a href="javascript:openVideo()"`

```
https://jsfiddle.net/awkbawgs/2/
```